# Locate a python script without absolute path

Tags: python, build

I am having problems with a python code. I am trying to follow back the trail of error messages to see if I can find the heart of the problem.

I get to the following:

`File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/george/gp.py", line 511, in predict`

But I can't find that file, as the path is not an absolute path.

How can I locate this python script please?

Comment: this is a relative path, have you tried to check from the current directory you're run the script from?

Comment: You could also always just search through your system for all gp.py files if you really wanted to find it one way or another.

Comment: There is no build directory in root or the path I'm running from. The problem probably stems from me not knowing / understanding what 'build' is.

Comment: I also tried to search, but somehow didn't find it.

Comment: What are you trying to run? That looks like something you'd get from a command like `python setup.py build`, where the `build` directory itself is not really interesting; `setup.py` copied your "real" code there before trying to do whatever it is its doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this message is built using `__file__` variable.

When running a script with a relative path, this path is kept in `__file__`. So the file must be found if you list it from the directory you ran the script from.

Example: I create a python file in `/foo/bar/test.py`: `print(__file__)`

Now I run it from `/foo` like this:

```
python bar/test.py
```

and it prints:

```
bar/test.py
```

Granted, the "current directory" may be more difficult to find if the launcher is wrapped in a shell which does `cd` ...